# Issue - applicationIconBadgeNumber - number exeeds 9999

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, user-experience, appearance

I am facing kind of weird requirements, which in real word I don't seem to exists. But, As a developer I don't ask for the reasons behind them :)

When working In a chat Application. I put BadgeNumber for each new message (expected behavior)

Now, while my tester tested it, they kept on pushing message to the other to the limit it (My App) gets failed. Now, When they failed to do so. They posted a weird bug.

They say for 9999 notification BadgeNumber shows as:

[image]

But, when next notification arrives ***It fails to shows that properly:***

[image]

Now, What am I supposed to do.

I know that's not going to happen (Consider from Developer point of view). But, How in hell would I resolve this?

Any guidance !!

Comment: What about showing **10K**

Comment: @AnoopVaidya a nice idea, but the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` is implemented as a number, not a string.

Comment: @GrahamLee: Also there is `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *badgeValue`

Comment: @AnoopVaidya no, there is no such thing on `UIApplication`

Comment: @rckoenes: that is in UITabBarItem, sorry if u all got irritated, I am learning iOS :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the Application badge you can only show numbers and you are passing a longer number than it can display it will truncate the number.

It will truncate the middle part of the number, this is why it is display `..` in the middle since it can't fit the number.

Since this is all handled by iOS there is nothing you can to to change the way it is presented.

If you want you can check the badge number server side and make sure that it not exceed `9999`.

Comment: No, nothing. Unless you set the maximun to `9999` serverside when sending the push notification.

Answer (score 1):

resolve the bug as **Known Limitation** or **Third Party** you can not do anything in it. put resolution as won't fix

Comment: @Viral: Appraisal time, take print out of this page and show to your manager :p

Comment: @Viral ... If we do not have control over certain things ... there is no way we can do anything about it. and this scenario is also rare ...